# Any difference in heap size between 32 bit JVM and Compressed Oops enabled 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, heap-memory

Running java Application in 32 bit JVM takes 20MB of heap memory. Same Application, if I run in 64 bit JVM by enabling Compressed Oops will it use same 20MB of memory or more memory?

Comment: What happens when you run it and measure heap usage?

Comment: This answer may prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130982/java-odd-memory-consumption-between-x32-and-x64/26132364#26132364. The app will probably still use more than 20MB of HEAP memory (how much more, depends on the data structures it is using, as Compressed Ooops will only compress certain pointers). In terms of off heap memory, things will be different.